# Scroll down between 2 points won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got code from question but I can't make it work with bootstrap

May edit is here
https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/147145/

and the orginal one is https://jsfiddle.net/fLyrg57t/65/

The issue is the code adds 1000px top from the beginning and the div will stick in footer

How can I make it this one work ??

Also  the code gives it fixed position

and this way it will not respect parent width like this code

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
```

Comment: the end point is the issue I guess

Comment: Even if I make #footer the endpoint it won't fix it   but in original example it works